# htaccess doesnt work on mobile browsers

Tags: .htaccess, mobile, browser

I have my htaccess code for rewrite rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/?$ search.php?q=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /search(?:\.php|)\?q=([^\ &]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]
```

On the pc browser it works well. If the user types in search "word" it will look like this:

```
www.name.com/word
```

And it works just fine, but when it comes to mobile browser I tested out (Samsung s6 phone) the link shows up as 404 page.. Why it doesnt work on the mobile? Do I need some extra code in htaccess file?

Comment: Is it still `www` when you're on a mobile or do you have a dedicated subdomain (such as `m` or `mobile` for instance) ?

Comment: Yes, I have not made it like a separate website for the mobile, I will just adjust the style with css for the mobile phones at this moment

Comment: Confusing !!! did you correct your code after the answer was sugested ? I' cannot find a difference in the code you post and the corrected code in the answer, so now I have no clue what was corrected ... so no info was relayed ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a problem with upper / lower case, try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/?$ search.php?q=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /search(?:\.php|)\?q=([^\ &]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]
```

Comment: It's strange how mistakes like this causes hours of research and disappointment..It works like a sharm! Thanks for that!

Comment: Unfortunately I know too! ;-)